# Why can laravel base users login into backpack's admin panel?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm just discovering backpack, have read the base documentation, installed the latest version without any problem (laravel 6 in homestead environment). Everything works perfectly, added some modules, played a bit with the cruds, etc.
Still, there's one thing i don't get : why can simple (base laravel) users login into the admin panel ?
I really don't like the idea to have an is_admin column in the users table, but prefer to have a completly separate table for admins.
When reading the docs i thought it was default behavior in backpack v4+ but i clearly misunderstood :)

What confuses me even more is the backpack guard. Why does it even exist if it doesn't prevent users to access backpack's admin panel ? why not use the web guard if the backpack guard doesn't do anything more ?

I'd be really thankful if someone could explain me the concept behind this and what i missed ! a link to a way to completly separate backpack and regular laravel users authentication would be nice too :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best way* for admins and users to get separated differs from project to project. Plus, it's a matter of opinion. By default, in Backpack we tried to cater to the 90% use case, and most projects either have *only* admins or store users *in the same table* with admins for convenience. But that's why we use a different guard, so that it's easy to change the default behaviour.

**The only thing the Backpack auth and the Laravel auth have in common is the User model.** You'll notice `App\Models\BackpackUser extends App\User`. If you want to use a different table to store your admins, this would make the admin/user separation complete:

#### Solution 1

- create a migration and model for your admins; you could [start from Laravel's](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php);
- make `App\Models\BackpackUser extend App\Models\Admin` instead of `User`;

#### Solution 2

[Use your own model](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/base-how-to#use-your-own-user-model-instead-of-backpackuser) instead of BackpackUser. If you need to keep the password reset functionality, you should also use the traits and methods in BackpackUser on your new Admin model.

Hope it helps.

--

PS. Backpack started from using Laravel's auth, and over the years has come to use separate views, controllers, guards etc - in order to make it easier for developers to customise it to their various needs. *Very few* people so far have complained about using the `users` table to store admins, so we kept it this way. If you think *the default* should be a separate `admins` table, I suggest you [open a thread in our Github](https://github.com/laravel-backpack/crud/) and give the team & community reasons to do so. If enough people are behind a change, it usually gets implemented.